# 'bool' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I am training a neural network and a part of my code has returned the following error:

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(truth,
                          predictions,
                          classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          save=False,
                          cmap=plt.cm.Oranges,
                          path="confusion_matrix.png"):

    acc = (np.array(truth) == np.array(predictions))
    size = float(acc.shape[0]) #error
    acc = np.sum(acc.astype("int32")) / size
    (...)




AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

function call

```
pred = pred.numpy()
plot_confusion_matrix(truth=labels.numpy(),
                      predictions=pred,
                      save=False,
                      path="logref_confusion_matrix.png",
                      classes=["forward", "left", "right"])
```

Where the thuth represents the labels of Y and predictions the array of prediction, both with shape 32, 3. I checked the update on numpy, ipython etc and all are updated, tried some modification, but without success.

Comment: What do you see for `acc.shape` ?

Comment: I edited my question, in case acc.shape will serve for normalization de acc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that acc would be a boolean and not a numpy array of booleans is that you are passing in a singular value for truth and predictions. In the code you provided, there would be no error for an actual array of 32x3. Look at the rest of your code and make sure you actually pass in an array to np.array() instead of singular values.

Comment: I edited the question to indicate the function call, as you see I called it as np.array ()

Comment: This is caused by other errors in your code. You can see this by using the value np.zeros((32,3)) for predictions and truth in the interpreter and then trying the value 3 and 5. (np.array(3) == np.array(5)) returns the boolean false, which is not a numpy array and therefore doesn't have a shape. Your issue is that that comparison line is not comparing actual arrays, so you need to trace your code back a bit to see what is happening. Printing out the values within your method or using the type function to see what is being passed in might help you debug, but what you gave isn't enough to debug.